# What does _ mean in Elm?

Tags: elm

I'm looking at the `zip` example on http://elm-lang.org/examples/zip and I had a question about what exactly the `_` means in Elm.

```
zip : List a -> List b -> List (a,b)
zip xs ys =
   case (xs, ys) of
    ( x :: xs', y :: ys' ) ->
        (x,y) :: zip xs' ys'

    (_, _) ->
        []
```

My hunch is that it means "everything else" but does that mean any valid value? What if there is no value?

Comment: As described by Dennis Reimann in this article. https://dennisreimann.de/articles/elm-data-structures-record-tuple.html

"Using _ one can define placeholders for values that will be ignored or skipped."

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`_` is used to match anything where you don't care about the value, so it's commonly used to match the "everything else" case.

In your example code `(_, _)` will match *any* tuple with 2 values in it. Note that it could also be replaced with just `_` since you end up not caring about either value. A more illustrative example would be where you care about one value from the tuple but not the other, for example the implementation of `fst` [in the core package](https://github.com/elm-lang/core/blob/09f3dd2b11f34987bf6b32201fd1899baff5d646/src/Basics.elm#L572)

```
fst : (a,b) -> a
fst (a,_) =
  a
```

We don't care about the second value in the tuple, so it just matches with an `_` in that position.

There is no `null` or `undefined` in Elm, so you don't have to worry about there being "no value" (if something would have no value, the [Maybe](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/core/3.0.0/Maybe) type is used).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! In the zip example, since List a and List b can be of different lengths, does the ( _ , _ ) case also take care of the scenario where a or b have different lengths? If so, wouldn't one of the "_" values be non-existent?

Comment: Yes, one or both of the lists will be an empty list ( `[ ]` ) if it doesn't match the first case (not non-existent, just empty :P ). The `_` will match anything including an empty list.

Comment: So if I'm understanding this correctly, when `(zip [] [])` happens, it won't fall into the first case because you can't destructure an empty array, and thus you reach the second case and since `_` accepts any list, it returns an empty list here. Is that accurate? And to confirm, if the ORDER of the 2 cases are switched, this function would be incorrect because it would always fall into the first case?